# VanillaJS to VueJS Error: bad element for Flickity: carousel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, flickity

I'm trying to get [this Flickity example](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/RNQgpB) (CodePen) to work in a VueJS component.

HTML

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 var flkty = new Flickity('.carousel');

    flkty.on( 'dragStart', function() {
      console.log('dragStart');
    });
```

I get this error:

> bad element for Flickity: carousel

My **not working** version:

JS data ()

```
import Flickity from 'flickity'
var flkty = new Flickity('.carousel')
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      flickityOptions: {
        dragThreshold: 50,
        initialIndex: 1,
        prevNextButtons: false,
        pageDots: false,
        wrapAround: false,
        hash: true,
        percentPosition: false
      },
```

JS mounted ()

```
  mounted () {
    flkty.on('dragStart', function () {
      this.stageDragging = true
      console.log('stageDragging: ' + this.stageDragging)
    })
    flkty.on('dragEnd', function () {
      this.stageDragging = false
      console.log('stageDragging: ' + this.stageDragging)
    })
```

How to use [this Flickity example](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/RNQgpB)  in a VueJS component?

Comment: You would likely need to consider using [ref](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to access the respective element/component or at minimum create an instance of `Flickity` in a lifecycle hook such as `mounted()` when the element is actually available in the DOM. That being said, there is [libraries/components](https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-flickity) made for Vue that use Flickity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `<script>` section, the JavaScript executes before the template has been rendered in the document, so Flickity wouldn't be able to find `.carousel` if called outside a hook. Vue instances have a [`mounted()` lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) that gets called when its template has rendered, which is where you should create the Flickity carousel:

```
// const flkty = new Flickity(...) // DON'T DO THIS HERE
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const flkty = new Flickity(...)
      // ...
    });
  }
}
```

Also, instead of passing the `.carousel` classname to Flickity, pass a [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to the `.carousel` element in order to avoid grabbing an unexpected `.carousel` element in the document (e.g., if you had multiple component instances).

```
// template
<div ref="carousel">

// script
new Flickity(this.$refs.carousel)
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/0or1orxr8v?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FCarousel.vue)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        dragThreshold: 50,
        initialIndex: 1,
        prevNextButtons: false,
        pageDots: false,
        wrapAround: false,
        hash: true,
        percentPosition: false,
      },
      itemsCount: 5,
      flkty: null,
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.flkty = new Flickity(`#${this.$el.id} .carousel`);
    this.flkty.on( 'dragStart', function() {
      console.log('dragStart');
    });
  }
})

Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.carousel {
  background: #FAFAFA;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 66%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #8C8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  counter-increment: carousel-cell;
}

.carousel-cell:before {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: counter(carousel-cell);
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div v-for="item in itemsCount" class="carousel-cell">{{ item }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Specific Rails case :**

the error Prompt because I had a double time the CDN script tag and JS code on my `Javascript/Packs` on the same `layout.html.erb`

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'flickity' %>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```