# Flickity API with Vue 3 and Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, flickity

I've been working with Flickity in my Vue 3 app, and it works fine when I use a hard-coded HTML carousel with static cells. I need to add cells programmatically at runtime, however, and I can't get the Flickity API to work correctly.

I'm trying to follow the `append()` example, but I get the error:

> ```
> flickity.js?1385:72 Bad element for Flickity: .carousel
> ```

in my inspector during runtime. I tried to follow the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54483754/vanillajs-to-vuejs-error-bad-element-for-flickity-carousel) and [here](https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-flickity/issues/52), but neither have been able to run successfully. It looks like it's due to TypeScript errors on the Flickity lib. I also installed `@types/flickity`, fyi.

What can I do to fix my `append` logic below?

```html
<template>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col d-block m-auto payment-option">
            <flickity ref="carousel" :options="flickityOptions">
            </flickity>
          </div>
      </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent} from "vue";
//import Flickity from 'vue-flickity/src/flickity.vue';
import Flickity from 'flickity'
export default defineComponent({
  name: "PageName",
  components: {
    Flickity
  },
  data() {
    return {
      flickityOptions: {
        initialIndex: 3,
        prevNextButtons: false,
        pageDots: true,
        wrapAround: true
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createBankAccountCarousel(flkty: Flickity) {
      flkty.append(this.makeFlickityCell())
    },
    makeFlickityCell() {
      const cell = document.createElement('div');
      cell.className = 'carousel-cell'
      cell.textContent = "Hi"
      return cell
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let flkty = new Flickity(this.$refs.carousel)
    this.createBankAccountCarousel(flkty)
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: no idea on flickity, but its not typescript, it's complaining it can't find the element, try adding class="carousel"  to the flickety component. not sure if that will help or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you were possibly trying [`vue-flickity`](https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-flickity) in Vue 3, but [that component was built for Vue 2](https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-flickity/blob/b4cff85/package.json#L36).

You can create your own `Flickity` component in Vue 3:

1. Create `Flickity.vue` with the following template and script, which applies a [template ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html) on the root element, and contains a [slot](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#slots) to receive `.carousel-cell` elements:

   ```html
   <template>
     <!--  template ref -->
     <div ref="root" class="flickity">
       <slot />
     </div>
   </template>

   <script lang="ts">
   import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

   export default defineComponent({
     setup() {
       const root = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null) // reference to template ref named "root"
       return {
         root,
       }
     }
   })
   </script>
   ```
2. Declare an `options` [prop](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#props), which we'll pass to the `Flickity` constructor later.

   ```html
   <script lang="ts">
   import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

   export default defineComponent({
     props: {
       options: Object,
     }
   })
   </script>
   ```
3. In the component's [`mounted` hook](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#mounted), instantiate `Flickity` with the `"root"` template ref and the `options` prop; and in [`unmounted`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#unmounted), destroy the `Flickity` instance:

   ```html
   <script lang="ts">
   import { defineComponent, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'
   import Flickity from 'flickity'

   export default defineComponent({
     setup(props) {
       let flickity: typeof Flickity | null = null
       onMounted(() => flickity = new Flickity(root.value as HTMLElement, props.options))
       onUnmounted(() => flickity?.destroy())
     }
   })
   </script>
   ```
4. Add a method named `"append"` to allow appending new elements to the carousel:

   ```html
   <script lang="ts">
   import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
   import Flickity from 'flickity'

   export default defineComponent({
     setup() {
       let flickity: typeof Flickity | null = null
       return {
         append(element: HTMLElement) {
           flickity?.append(element)
           flickity?.select(-1)
         }
       }
     }
   })
   </script>
   ```
5. Create `src/flickity.d.ts` with the following type declarations (if using VS Code, you'll have to restart the IDE for these typings to be indexed):

   ```js
   declare module 'flickity' {
     const Flickity: {
       new (el: string | HTMLElement, options?: Record<string, unknown>): this
       append(element: HTMLElement)
       destroy()
       select(id: string | number)
     }
     export = Flickity
   }
   ```
6. Add the following `<style>` block, which pulls in the `flickity` default styles, and styles the `.carousel-cell` elements that would be received in the slot:

   ```html
   <style scoped>
   @import '~flickity/dist/flickity.css';

   .flickity .carousel {
     background: #EEE;
     margin-bottom: 40px;
   }
   /* use ::v-deep to get at slot elements */
   .flickity::v-deep .carousel-cell {
     height: 200px;
     width: 25%;
     margin: 0 10px;
     background: #6C6;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     border-radius: 8px;
   }
   </style>
   ```

#### Example Usage:

```html
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <flickity ref="flickity" :options="flickityOptions">
      <div class="carousel-cell">1</div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">2</div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">3</div>
    </flickity>
    <div class="actions">
      <button @click="addElement">Append element</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import Flickity from './components/Flickity.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Flickity
  },
  data() {
    return {
      flickityOptions: {
        pageDots: true,
        wrapAround: true,
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addElement() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
      (this.$refs.flickity as any).append(this.makeFlickityCell())
    },
    makeFlickityCell() {
      const cell = document.createElement('div')
      cell.className = 'carousel-cell'
      cell.textContent = 'Hi'
      return cell
    }
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped>
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 50vh;
}
</style>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-flickity-ts?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: vue-flickity source code is fairly simple. What is in it that prevents it from working properly in Vue3?

Comment: Vue 3 is not backward compatible with Vue 2, which `vue-flickity` depends on. Since the underlying Vue API has changed, Vue 2 component libraries cannot just be dropped into a Vue 3 project.